# Remove Newline Character between two specific strings

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am using Unix Shell. How to remove newline character between two specific strings.

For example, input is:

```
CASE when a in ('abcd','bdcdf') then
  Shng,
END as xyz
```

Output should be:

```
CASE when a in ('abcd','bdcdf') then Shng END as xyz,
```

Comment: this is quite broad. What is the logic underlying this? what have you tried?

Comment: My scenario is like... i have SQL File in which these case statements are like this.... i want to remove all the newline characters between  case and end statement

Answer (score 0):

Parse the file line for line and remember when you see a CASE or END.
The code beneath uses a short syntax for an if-statement and an echo that suppresses \n by the -n parameter.

```
incase=0
cat x.sql | while read -r line; do
   [[ ${line} = CASE* ]] && incase=1;
   [[ ${line} = END* ]] && incase=0
   [[ ${incase} = 0 ]] && echo "${line}"
   [[ ${incase} = 1 ]] && echo -n "${line} "                                               
done
```

EDIT:
When you have nested CASEs (like CASE ... CASE ... END ... END) and all
CASEs start on different lines you can count how deep your nested.

```
incase=0
cat x.sql | while read -r line; do
   [[ ${line} = CASE* ]] && (( incase = incase + 1)) ;
   [[ ${line} = END* ]] && (( incase = incase - 1)) 
   [[ ${incase} = 0 ]] && echo "${line}"
   [[ ${incase} > 0 ]] && echo -n "${line} "                                               
done
# You might want an extra echo here so your last line will finish with a \n
echo
```

EDIT 2: Often you can avoid cat (look for UUOC). Here the code is better as

```
incase=0
cat x.sql | while read -r line; do
   [[ ${line} = CASE* ]] && incase=1;
   [[ ${line} = END* ]] && incase=0
   [[ ${incase} = 0 ]] && echo "${line}"
   [[ ${incase} = 1 ]] && echo -n "${line} "                                               
done
```

EDIT:
When you have nested CASEs (like CASE ... CASE ... END ... END) and all
CASEs start on different lines you can count how deep your nested.

```
incase=0
while read -r line; do
   [[ ${line} = CASE* ]] && (( incase = incase + 1)) ;
   [[ ${line} = END* ]] && (( incase = incase - 1)) 
   [[ ${incase} = 0 ]] && echo "${line}"
   [[ ${incase} > 0 ]] && echo -n "${line} "                                               
done < x.sql
# You might want an extra echo here so your last line will finish with a \n
echo
```

Comment: will it work if i have nested case statements??  sorry but i m new to unix scripting

Comment: New in unix scripting, have fun, I adjusted the answer. Remark:
`[[ sometest ]] && action` stands for `if [[ sometest ]]; then action; fi`